# Asp.NET MVC 5 Trace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, redirect, logging, trace

I am having some issue on MVC 5, when I am in any controller action the flow redirect to LogOff action method on Account controller.
I didn't find why that is happening so I want to know if there is any Trace or Debug, or Log, or whatever that I should look at to see why this is happening.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mentioned this route logic somewhere thats why it is redirecting to logoff action method. Please check routeconfig, web.config and layout, where i think you will find something regarding this by which you can resolve this issue.

Comment: I searched in the code files and there is no redirect to LogOff. That's why I need a tracer